# Refereencing a key vault uri using resourceId how can the resource group be referenced in bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I have the bicep code module below which adds a customer managed key onto a storage account, the issue is that it expects the key vault to be in thesame resource group as the storage account which may not be the case.

Looking at the `keyvaulturi`, is it possible to reference it by also including the resource group when the `resourceid` function is evaluated, this way it can reference the correct key vault.

The end goal is to rewrite the bicep module that creates the storage account such that the customer managed key is created at thesame time rather than running two seperate modules.

```
resource AssignCMKtoStorageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: AssignCMKtoStorageAccountName
  location: location
  tags: appliedTags
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: skuName
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
    }
    encryption: {
      services: {
        file: {
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Keyvault'
      keyvaultproperties: {
        keyname: CMKName
        keyvaulturi: reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', keyVaultName), '2016-10-01', 'full').properties.vaultUri
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`resourceId` function will allow you to pass the resource group name:

```
param keyVaultName string
param keyVaultRGName string

keyvaulturi: reference(resourceId(keyVaultRGName, 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', keyVaultName), '2016-10-01', 'full').properties.vaultUri
```

Tho Bicep recommends using `existing` resource so something like that would work as well:

```
param keyVaultName string
param keyVaultRGName string

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
  scope: resourceGroup(keyVaultRGName)
}

resource AssignCMKtoStorageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  ...
  properties: {
    ...
    encryption: {
      ...
      keyvaultproperties: {
        ...
        keyvaulturi: keyVault.properties.vaultUri
      }
    }
  }
}
```